# Issue in form authentication using sitefinity and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, telerik, forms-authentication, sitefinity

I have integrated Sitefinity with my asp.net application.

When I am executing below mentioned code , it is setting 3 cookies.

```
TelerikSecurity.SecurityManager.AuthenticateUser(Membership.Provider.Name, username, password, isRememberMe)
```

A_authCookie , B_RoleCookie , C_loggingcookie in HttpCookieCollection collection of HttpResponse class.

I am also doing forms authentication after that.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(formValidationObj.Email, formValidationObj.RememberMe);
```

Issue : If I am passing the value of isRememberMe false in 
    `TelerikSecurity.SecurityManager.AuthenticateUser`
 method but  true in

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie
```

method , remember me functionality is not working , i.e. when I close the browser and open it , I have to do the login again. because I do not get the value of A_authCookie on reopening the browser
But if I pass the value as true in

```
TelerikSecurity.SecurityManager.AuthenticateUser`
```

remember me functionality starts working because I got the value of A_authCookie on reopening the browser.

Why remember me functionality is dependent on A_authCookie , which is provided and managed by sitefinity and how can I fix this issue ?

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sitefinity handles the creation of all security cookies during its authentication process. The correct entry point is in the security manager:

```
SecurityManager.AuthenticateUser(null, username, rememberMe, out user);
```

Note the documentation:

**If successful the  method execution results in setting the current thread principal to the authenticated user and issuing a authentication cookie**

The reason that it's especially important to not tamper with the authentication process of Sitefinity is that the underlying authentication mechanism is actually by default Claims authentication -- regardless of whether or not it stores information in the forms auth cookie.